# How to fill a rectangle that has one side curved in flutter?

Tags: flutter, canvas, path, rect

I'm trying to fill a curved rectangle, but it is overflowing from the curved part, have used paths to create this shape. Any suggestions for how to achieve this.

Or is there any way to create a rectangle with 4 offset values, whose one side is curved like this?
I have offset values of two straight line (x1,y1), (x2,y2), (x3,y3) and (x4,y4). Any references?

```
      final path = Path();
      path.moveTo(87.75, 10.06);
      path.lineTo(263.25, 80.06);

      path.lineTo(263.25, 359.0);
      path.lineTo(87.75, 359.0);
      canvasWrapper.drawPath(path, _barAreaPaint..color = Colors.red);
```

[image]

Comment: Can you provide full widget that will reproduce this issue? instead of using `lineTo` try Quadratic curves

Comment: I'm not sure if I will be be able to provide all the necessary codes to reproduce this issue because the current ui are from several different files, some of which are custom library. Is there a different way to create this type of user interface. I have modified the fl_chart package to get this behaviour. Any other sources to check out?

Comment: You might find a way of clipping/cutting this on canvas

Comment: I have offset values for the two straight lines ((x1,y1), (x2,y2), (x3,y3) and (x4,y4)coordinate points), is there any way to create one side filled curved rectangle with these values?

Comment: yes I think, if you can handle control point try `Path()..quadraticBezierTo`

Answer (score 0):

Try drawing an arc

```
Rect rect = Rect.fromLTWH(0.0, 0.0, size.width, size.height);
path.arcTo(
        rect,
        0.0,
        pi / 2,//adjust radians accordingly
        false);
  }
```